# Как обработать сигнал key-press-event?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, gtk+

К сигналу `press-key-event` виджета `TextView` подключил свой обработчик:

```
void event_return(GtkWidget *widget,GdkEventKey  *event,sig_data *data)
{
    if(event->keyval==GDK_KEY_Return){
        printf("\nEVENT_RETURN\n");
    }
}
```

То есть, если я нажму клавишу `Enter` то сработает мой обработчик и в буфер виджета `TextView` эта клавиша не пойдет(как и нажатие любой клавиши). Так и есть, **НО**, если я добавлю `sleep(1)` в код:

```
void event_return(GtkWidget *widget,GdkEventKey  *event,sig_data *data)
{
    if(event->keyval==GDK_KEY_Return){
        printf("\nEVENT_RETURN\n");
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

То символ перевода строки пойдет в буфер. Почему так происходит, как перехватить этот сигнал полностью и не пропустить его в буфер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На меил ответах дали ответ: https://otvet.mail.ru/question/220446877

Обработчик key-press-event должен возвращать значение типа gboolean. Это значение и определяет, будет ли дальше происходить обработка по умолчанию: TRUE - прервать, FALSE - продолжить.

> > Почему так происходит

Вызывающая сторона читает значение регистра RAX, думая что в нём лежит ожидаемое возвращаемое значение. В первом случае там оказывается ненулевое значение, что расценивается как TRUE. Во втором же случае последним записанным в RAX значением оказывается то, которое вернула функция sleep, а она в случае удачного завершения возвращает 0 (т. е. FALSE).

P.s даже и подумать не мог что вызывающая сторона будет читать значение из регистра

Comment: Вообще то в документации на [сигнал](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-key-press-event) об этом четко написано.

Comment: @Yaroslav вы вопрос читали? Мне также интересно было почему мой код иногда работает, а иногда нет. На меил сру объяснили, что берется значение из регистра  А про документацию да, я читал ее, но на момент написания вопроса невнимательно, уже после ответа внимательнее прочитал